# Google Search Console Sitemap Error Invalid URL

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap, invalid-url

I am seeing gibberish in my source code as a duplicate url for my Image:loc. Meaning it comes up twice one for example:

```
<loc>https://www.acsecapital.com/how-to-get-a-business-line-of-credit/</loc>
        <lastmod>2020-05-28T02:33:29+00:00</lastmod>
        <image:image>
            <image:loc>http://@ET-DC@eyJkeW5hbWljIjp0cnVlLCJjb250ZW50IjoicG9zdF9mZWF0dXJlZF9pbWFnZSIsInNldHRpbmdzIjp7fX0=@</image:loc>
```

I am lost as how to remove that gibberish image url. Can someone help with this issue?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: There's no way to help you as we have no idea how that file is generated

Comment: Thanks for the guidance John. I appreciate it. And I believe it was generated by RankMath.